# Reactjs and Firebase API JSON format

Tags: reactjs, json, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

So I am to receive raw JSON data I from a firebase realtime database link I was provided (link can be found in my code below). I'm trying to capture this data and display it on a simple HTML table just for testing purposes.

I've tested my code first with data from a random API generator. And it works fine.

**TEST API DATA**

```
[
{
"userId": 1,
"id": 1,
"title": "sunt aut facere repellat provident occaecati excepturi optio reprehenderit",
"body": "quia et suscipit\nsuscipit recusandae consequuntur expedita et cum\nreprehenderit molestiae ut ut quas totam\nnostrum rerum est autem sunt rem eveniet architecto"
},
{
"userId": 1,
"id": 2,
"title": "qui est esse",
"body": "est rerum tempore vitae\nsequi sint nihil reprehenderit dolor beatae ea dolores neque\nfugiat blanditiis voluptate porro vel nihil molestiae ut reiciendis\nqui aperiam non debitis possimus qui neque nisi nulla"
}
]
```

and this is the raw JSON data I will actually be using and receiving from the Realtime firebase

**FIREBASE JSON DATA**

> ```
> {
>     "1": {
>     "category": "Thesis",
>     "department": "CPE",
>     "id": 1,
>     "title": "E-nose Based Classification of Drying Method Using Local Tea Leaves Gas Signature"
>     },
>     "2": {
>     "category": "Thesis",
>     "department": "CPE",
>     "id": 2,
>     "title": "Tongue Biometrics Extraction Based on YOLO Algorithm and CNN Inception"
>     },
> ```
>
> }

I'm using the following code below in ReactJS trying to display the data. But it seems that the raw format from the firebase API isn't in the correct format since it's not in in an array? (Or its not in brackets?) So, errors are popping out that *data.map* is the source of the error.

> ```
>     import Axios from "axios";
> import "./App.css";
> import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
>
> function App() {
>   const [data, setData] = useState([]);
>
>   useEffect(() => {
>     Axios.get(
>       "https://ojt-thesis-e37ae-default-rtdb.asia-southeast1.firebasedatabase.app/thesis-titles.json"
>     )
>       .then((res) => {
>         console.log("Getting from ::::", res.data);
>         setData(res.data);
>       })
>       .catch((err) => console.log(err));
>   }, []);
>
>   const arr = JSON.parse(
>     data.map((data, index) => {
>       return (
>         <tr>
>           <td>{data.id}</td>
>           <td>{data.title}</td>
>           <td>{data.category}</td>
>         </tr>
>       );
>     })
>   );
>
>   return (
>     <div className="App">
>       <h1>Sample API App</h1>
>       <table>
>         <tr>
>           <th>ID </th>
>           <th>Title</th>
>           <th>Category</th>
>         </tr>
>         {arr}
>       </table>
>     </div>
>   );
> }
>
> export default App;
> ```

I tried to parse the raw firebase data using the *JSON.parse* function hoping it might convert it into a proper JSON object, but to no avail. Kind of still scratching my head how I could convert the formatting to one that would work with the method I'm attempting. Still kind new to using API in REACTJs. Any help and tips would be great!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can get the values of `object` in an Array using [Object.values](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values) method, which I assume is the result you may want here.

you can just do as below and the **parsing** is also not required while using `map` ...

`setData(Object.values(res.data));`

It would be something as so from which you can use `map` to iterate over and render data

```js
const res = {
    "1": {
    "category": "Thesis",
    "department": "CPE",
    "id": 1,
    "title": "E-nose Based Classification of Drying Method Using Local Tea Leaves Gas Signature"
    },
    "2": {
    "category": "Thesis",
    "department": "CPE",
    "id": 2,
    "title": "Tongue Biometrics Extraction Based on YOLO Algorithm and CNN Inception"
    }, 
}

console.log(Object.values(res))
```

you can remove the **parsing** as well as below which I was mentioning in above statements :

```
const arr = data.map((data, index) => {
  return (
    <tr>
      <td>{data.id}</td>
      <td>{data.title}</td>
      <td>{data.category}</td>
    </tr>
  );
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much, it worked and everything runs smoothly now